# How do I keep the gaussian blur with the same size and outline when downsizing?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

I applied a gaussian blur to the shape on the left and when I try to downsize it to 24 px wide, the gaussian blur creates a "circle" around it (as shown on the shape on the right) rather than just the outline of the shape. How do I prevent that from happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have scale effects on?

Comment: Yeah I do; and it didn't work. But I just decided to do it mathematically and manually to figure out what it would be when I scaled it since I can't find an easier way to do it. I just took the width and height of the original and width and height of the desired size and found the percentage it took to decrease it. Then took the percentage and multiplied that by the value amount of the gaussian blur of the original and divided it by 100. It's the long and tedious way of doing it and I probably made no sense to you but it works. If showed you on paper it'd make sense!

Comment: The gaussian works like that. Anyway check that the gaussian is actually part of the thing you scale. So for example gaussian applied to layer is not affected by change of object. Similarily selecting components (with white arrow) does not select the appearance so can not scale.

Comment: If all else fails, making the graphic into a symbol and resizing the symbol should work.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on how you're using your object, the only way I've been able to have my blurs stay when resizing is a cheat way.

What I did was save my blurred object as its own PDF, then place that PDF within the Illustrator file I'm working in. You can then resize that object to any size and it'll keep your effects, strokes, and so on, that didn't scale before, intact. The downsize is it's not editable directly unless you open that PDF and edit it separately.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do (keeping in mind that it's a destructive solution though) is to expand the layer with the gaussian blur (in this case the white one) so it will keep it's exact appearance.

Comment: It will not be that exact. Rasterised effect scaling can lead to destruction of the smoothness of the gradients. Bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

Just save the image with the blur as a separate **.ai** file. Then, drag that file back into the one you're working in as a linked image, then you can scale it up and down without affecting the blur. You can also re-edit the file by clicking on *Edit Original* in the links palette.

Answer (score 1):

With the command "Expand Appearance" in Objects it is possible to scale a gauss-blur without having any issues.